# Session auto terminate in Codeigniter after i download file

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, session, download

An user of my system need to login first to used the function available in the system (then it will create an session for the user). However, if the user download a content from the system, the session will auto terminate. The download will be from my own server as i run it on localhost. As far as i know, the session will terminate if only i run the session_destroy() by clicking the logout button.

[image: This is the code for the download function.]

This is my form, if the user click download it will run the download function

```html
 <form class="" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/com_auth/download">
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Download">
```

Hope someone can help me as download function is essential for my system. Thanks in advance!

Comment: force download sends headers and so does redirect. you can't have both unless you are using multi headers which is difficult (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=force+download+and+redirect). in this circumstance you can probably destroy the session before the force download however the user won't see a notice or be redirected (however they will be logged out).